# How to use a nested form with Mongoid without Rails?

Tags: html, forms, mongoid, nested-attributes

Working on a Rack app (not Rails) with Mongoid. According to the [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/nested_attributes.html), a document with an embedded document looks like:

```
class Band
  field :name, String

  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :manager
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :manager
end

class Manager
  field :name, String
end
```

How to create a single form for a Band, that allows you to set the Manager's name?

```
<form>
  <input type='text' name='name'> <!-- Band name -->
  <input type='text' name='name'> <!-- Manager name -->
```

FWIW, using [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).